# Why is Qt reporting > 14000 errors in this one page source file?

Tags: qt, file, qt-creator

Here is the code:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QProcessEnvironment>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QProcessEnvironment env;

    // Environment variables required by CGI apps

    env.insert("QUERY_STRING",      url.encodedQuery());
    env.insert("REQUEST_URI",       url.toString());
    env.insert("REQUEST_METHOD",    "GET");
    env.insert("REMOTE_ADDR",       pSocket->peerAddress().toString());

    //==========

    QProcess process;
    process.setProcessEnvironment(env);
    process.start("php-cgi",QProcess::ReadWrite);

    process.write("<?php print_r($_GET); ?>");
    process.closeWriteChannel();

    process.waitForFinished();

    qDebug(process.readAll().data());

    return 0;
}
```

Qt Creator reports more than 14000 errors. Here is a small sample of them:

```
In file included from ../QProcess/main.cpp:2:
../QProcess/QProcess:1: error: stray ‘\177’ in program
../QProcess/QProcess:1: error: stray ‘\2’ in program
../QProcess/QProcess:1: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
../QProcess/QProcess:1: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
In file included from ../QProcess/main.cpp:2:
../QProcess/QProcess:1:8: warning: null character(s) ignored
../QProcess/QProcess:1: error: stray ‘\2’ in program
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example instance of this error. The contents of a file called new.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::cout << "Brand new." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Now compile it:

```
ppu32-g++ new.cpp -o new
```

No problem. Let's compile it again:

```
ppu32-g++ new.cpp -o new
```

OMG! Screen after screen of errors! Most of these errors look like this:

```
./new:1: error: stray '\177' in program
```

The problem is that the compiler is trying to use the **new** file in the current directory, as the C++ standard library `<new>`; used by `<iostream>`. In fact any file in the current directory, named after a C++ standard library header, which is used in the code being compiled, will likely cause an error. That our problem file is an executable obfuscates the error messages.

It doesn't occur on all the gcc machines I've tried. `ppu32-g++` 4.1.1 on PS3 Cell Fedora Linux certainly chokes.

Answer (score 1):

If that problem arises not on every host then probably difference in the compiler. Difference is likely in the header files directory scan order.
Such error should not arise if standard headers directory scanned **before** others.

As a workaround its enough to remove project target file manually befor building target. But this is not a programmers way (which are very lazy creatures).

Programmers way - is to learn QMake to delete target file just before project sources compilations (but under this way link phase will be done permanently). For me (QMake 2.01a under Linux) this is achived by addition of following lines into project file:

```
deltarget.commands = $$QMAKE_DEL_FILE $$TARGET
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += deltarget
PRE_TARGETDEPS += deltarget
```

This declares target *deltarget* which becomes built **before** current project.
This sample uses undeclared in QMake's manual variable **QMAKE_DEL_FILE** which used to remove files (its content of course platfrom-dependent).